# COUNT returning NULL, should return 0

Tags: oracle

I have a simple query for the table:

```
Person id Organization id  employee_nam age  busines_group_id
123       Zuyo         10     John      30   81
2457      Zuyo         10     Geet      69   81
56        Ghiya        12     paul      20   81 
          frei         13                    81

SELECT
    COUNT(DISTINCT ped.person_id)
FROM
    per_emp_detail ped
WHERE
    ped.business_group_id = 81
    AND
    ped.id = NVL(p_org_id, ped.organization_id);

SELECT
    NVL(COUNT(DISTINCT ped.person_id), 0)
FROM
    per_emp_detail ped
WHERE
    ped.business_group_id = 81
    AND
    ped.id = NVL(p_org_id, ped.organization_id);
```

`p_org_id` is the parameter which I am passing which can be 10, 12, or 13.
`COUNT` returns `2` for id 10. `1` for id 12. but is returning `NULL` for id 13.
I want `0` to be returned in this case.

`NVL` and `CASE` are also not working.

Comment: `nvl(count(distinct ped.person_id), 0)`

Comment: Its not working. i tried.

Comment: `count()` can't return null. Presumably this is PL/SQL or `p_org_id` wouldn't make sense, so is this actually your code - have you removed the `into` part, or is it a cursor? Either way showing other code might reveal an issue with how this is used. Your column names look a bit odd too, so perhaps post the actual table definition too.

Comment: Turn http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f9147/1 into something which produces results.

Comment: actual tables are from oracle hrms.. with  the same data .. and this  code is from a function where parameter is p_org_id and couunt is getting returned

Comment: So please show the function code - we can't tell what it returns or if that can be null - if the return always actually refers to the count result, or if there are other conditions etc. that can make it return early.

Comment: how about: `select id, count(*) from  per_emp_detail where (..) group by id`? that would be a basic sql syntax

Comment: done. but count still comes null

Comment: @sonakshisinha - the problem is not the query you've shown, it's something else in your function (or maybe how it's being called). We won't be able to help you if you don't add the function code to the question.

Comment: Agree with alex -- COUNT(*) never returns NULL. Look elsewhere for the problem.

Comment: I got teh answer i used  union :) Thnx all

Answer (score 1):

try MAX:

```
nvl(max(count(DISTINCT ped.person_id)),0)
```